# Maximum number not coprime to V

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a fixed array A of N integers where N<=100,000 and all elements of array are also less than or equal to 100,000.  The numbers in A are not monotonically increasing or contiguous or otherwise conveniently organized.

Now I am given up to 100,000 queries of the form {V, L, R} where in each query I need to find the largest number A[i] with i in the range [L,R] that is not coprime with the given value V. (That is GCD(V,A[i]) is not equal to 1.)

If it's is not possible, then also tell that all numbers in the given range are coprime to V.

A basic approach would be to iterate from each A[i] between L and R and compute GCD with value V and hence find maximum.  But is there any better way to do it if the number of queries can be up to 100,000 too. In that case, it's too inefficient to check for each number each time.

Example:

- Let us have N=6 and the array be [1,2,3,4,5,4] and let V be 2 and range [L,R] is [2,5].
- Then the answer is 4.

Explanation:

```
GCD(2,2)=2
GCD(2,3)=1
GCD(2,4)=2
GCD(2,5)=1
```

So maximum is 4 here.

Comment: Is this an online judge problem? Can you please post a link?

Comment: It's from the running codechef challenge. I would discourage users from spoiling the fun by posting solutions here

Comment: Try to use segment tree + RMQ

Comment: @TejasPatel How to use RMQ in this problem ?

Comment: I came to know its a contest question, so I would rather not discuss it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a large array but only one `V`, it should be faster to start by factorizing `V`.  After that your coprime test becomes simply finding the remainder modulo each unique factor of `V`.

Comment: But each query will be having a different V.Could you please elaborate your approach?Also what you mean by saying " finding the remainder modulo each unique factor of V."

Comment: @user3405426: I mean that if `V = pow(2,17) * 3;` then instead of `GCD(n, V) == 1` you can test that `n % 2 == 0 && n % 3 == 0`, which is both simpler than a GCD and short-circuits.  You'll need to run the factorization once per query, which is far better than  once per array element.

Comment: A piece of algorithm will be very helpful.am not getting u like this.But do you want me to check for each element in the range ?Its not any better than simply checking GCD with each element

Comment: @user3405426: Go back to the definition of coprime.  It means there is no factor of `n` that is also a factor of `V`.  Clearly for any `k` which is a cofactor of `n` and `V`, all factors of `k` are also cofactors.  So one only needs to consider prime factors, without repetition.  And it short-circuits -- as soon as *any* factor of `V` is found to divide `n`, you know they are not coprime.

Comment: @user3405426: Why do you say it is not better?  First, while `V` has no more than `O(log V)` prime factors, some may be repeated.  And there is short-circuiting.  So the number of steps will be less, on average, than the number of modulos computed during GCD.

Comment: Yeah i got you.But i had to check for it for each element of the range once right for each of the distinct prime factor of V in the worst case am i right ?

Comment: @user3405426: Factor `V` once, then check each element against the known factors of V, stopping if you find any cofactor.

Comment: Ok i agree i will get those numbers that are not coprime to V.But how to ensure maximum one ?

Comment: @user3405426: Same way you find maximum of any dataset -- replace it when you find a larger solution.  Note that here's another optimization opportunity, you can prune numbers that aren't larger than the current solution and not even test them for coprimeness.  It can work to sort the array and start from the largest end, so you can stop after finding a single solution.  But I doubt that will improve performance.  Searching a sorted array in ascending order would be bad though.

Comment: V has no more than O(log V) prime factors ?really?Means 10^5 number can have maximum of 12 prime factors right ?So in worst i had to check with 12 numbers with eah element of array

Comment: @user3405426 - O(log V), but really: floor(lg(V)), or the number of significant bits of (V) - 1. Since 2 is the smallest prime and 2^16 = 65536 < 10^5 < 2^17, a number N <= 10^5 has at most 16 prime factors. However, you only need *distinct* prime factors. And the largest number of distinct primes with a product <= 10^5 is {2 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13}. Any product of 7 or more distinct primes will be > 10^5.

Comment: @BenVoigt with m being the number of queries, O(m*n) is too slow for the given input constraints (the code is supposed to run in under a second or so). There are O((n + m) log n * number of distinct prime factors) solutions

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that

```
V = p_1*...*p_n
```

where p_i is a prime number (you can restrict it to distinct primes only). Now the answer is

```
result = -1
for p_i:
    res = floor(R / p_i) * p_i
    if res >= L and res > result:
        result = res
```

So if you can factorize `V` fast then this will be quite efficient.

**EDIT** I didn't notice that the array does not have to contain all integers. In that case sieve it, i.e. given prime numbers p_1, ..., p_n create a "reversed" sieve (i.e. all multiples of primes in range `[L, R]`). Then you can just do an intersection of that sieve with your initial array.

**EDIT2** To generate the set of all multiples you can use this algorithm:

```
primes = [p_1, ..., p_n]
multiples = []
for p in primes:
    lower = floor(L / p)
    upper = floor(R / p)
    for i in [lower+1, upper]:
        multiples.append(i*p)
```

The imporatant thing is that it follows from math that `V` is coprime with **every** number in range `[L, R]` which is not in `multiples`. Now you simply do:

```
solution = -1
for no in initial_array:
    if no in multiples:
        solution = max(solution, no)
```

Note that if you implement `result` as a set, then `if no in result:` check is `O(1)`.

**EXAMPLE** Let's say that `V = 6 = 2*3` and `initial_array = [7,11,12,17,21]` and `L=10` and `R=22`. Let's start with multiples. Following the algorithm we obtain that

```
multiples = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

First 7 are multiples of 2 (in range [10, 22]) and last 4 are multiples of 3 (in range [10, 22]). Since we are dealing with sets (`std::set`?) then there will be no duplicates (12 and 18):

```
multiples = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 15, 21]
```

Now go through the `initial_array` and check what values are in `multiples`. We obtain that the biggest such number is `21`. And indeed `21` is not coprime with `6`.

Comment: what is L here .Lower limit of range ?Am not understanding what you had written please make it clear

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question .I need to find maximum value FROM THE ARRAY that is not coprime with V

Comment: @user3405426 Yep, `[L, R]` is the range. I've refactored the psuedocode.

Comment: @freakish: It seems that not all numbers in the range `[L,R]` are candidates, only those that appear in the array.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah right.Elements from Left index of array(L) to right index of array{R) are only included to be taken into consideration

Comment: @user3405426 Ah, I see. I thought that the array contains all integers.

Comment: @user3405426: Is it `a[i] >= R` or `i >= R`?  Doesn't matter all that much, this test is cheap compared to GCD or modulo.

Comment: @freakish please explain " create a "reversed" sieve (i.e. all common multiples). Then you can just do an intersection of that sieve with your initial array."

Comment: @freakish you still missing something in your approach.You think creating a sieve will do the work here?

Comment: @user3405426 Right. Implement a loop that will generate a set of all multiples of primes (that's what I call a "reversed" sieve, because you are not looking for primes like with normal sieve), i.e. a set of the form `{a_1*p_1+...+a_n*p_n}` where `a_i` are integers such that values are bounded by `[L, R]`. Every other number is coprime with `V`. Once you have it you can just loop through your original array and check whether values are in the set of multiples. If they are take the maximal one. As for your question: what do you mean? That's my solution. If it is wrong then please point it out.

Comment: @freakish Tell first how are you making this set of multiple {a_1*p_1+...+a_n*p_n}.I didnt get it.

Comment: @user3405426 Sorry, pluses were wrong. What I should write is `{a_1*p_1, ..., a_n*p_n}` over all integers. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @freakish please explain by some example .Am getting confused and more confused.Suppose i have result array now .Then what to do next to find maximum element from given array which is not coprime?Is it necesary that the number of array to be in this result array.Their can be some numbers that have a prime factor other than the prime factor of V but has one of factors of V in common and yet be the maximum element

Comment: @freakish whats the time complexity of yourr algorithm for each query from L to R.Is it better than approach by Ben Voigt solution?Isnt it better to check with only prime factors of V if it divides then obviously they are not coprime and then their is no need to find your result set.Am i wrong ?

Comment: @user3405426 I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: @user3405426 It depends on initial values. Checking whether something divides something is quite expensive (`O(logn)` vs `O(1)` existance check in my case), especially since you have to go through all values. If the initial array is quite dense and `V` has only big prime factors (possibly prime itself) then my algorithm will be more efficient.

Comment: @freakish firstly by range i mean indexes of array and not the values.

Comment: @freakish sorry to say but you misinterpreted the whole question.

Comment: @user3405426 Dude, `number in range` is something else then `number with index in range`. I did not misinterpreted anything. You just asked different question then your intention was. I'm going to leave my solution, cause it is efficient and might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Bernstein's ["Factoring into coprimes in essentially linear time"](http://cr.yp.to/papers.html#dcba) (Journal of Algorithms 54:1, 1-30 (2005)) answers a similar question, and is used to identify bad (repeat factor) RSA moduli by Nadia Heninger's ["New research: There's No Need to Panic Over Factorable Keys--Just Mind Your Ps and Qs"`](http://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/nadiah/new-research-theres-no-need-panic-over-factorable-keys-just-mind-your-ps-and-qs). The problem there is to find common factors between a huge set of very large numbers, without going a pair at a time.

Comment: @user3405426, finding factors *is* a big deal. And Pollard rho doesn't work exactly in time O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Factor each of A's elements and store, for each possible prime factor, a sorted list of the numbers that contain this factor.

Given a number n contains O(log n) prime factors, this list will use O(N log N) memory.

Then, for each query (V, L, R), search for each prime factor in V, what is the maximum number that contain that factor within [L, R] (this can be done with a simple binary search).

Comment: Please provide some algorithm or example to do so.I think your solution is better than others .

Comment: I didnt ge your line " Factor each of A's elements and store, for each possible prime factor, a sorted list of the numbers that contain this factor."